# Alguna forma de mejorar esto?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Pues estaba revisando código antiguo y he visto esta monstruosidad.

```
    #pvp1
    if pvp1<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp2
    if pvp2<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp3
    if pvp3<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp4
    if pvp4<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp5
    if pvp5<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp6
    if pvp6<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp7
    if pvp7<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
    #pvp8
    if pvp8<pco:
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
        continue
```

¿Hay alguna manera de mejorarlo?
Este bloque de codigo está en un bucle, guardando todas las variables (pvp1,pvp2...) y haciendo esas condiciones. Hay algo parecido a:

if [pvp1,pvp2,pvp3...]

Saludos.

EDIT:

```
Al añadir el any y probarlo, me da error, diciendo que no encuentra la variable pco.
```

Añado el codigo desde el bucle.

```
for cdar in articulos:
    articulo=lee('articulos',cdar)
    if articulo==1:continue
    ardeno=articulo['AR_DENO']
    pvp1=articulo['AR_PVP1'] #inicial
    pvp2=articulo['AR_PVP2'] #promocion
    pvp3=articulo['AR_PVP3'] #rebajas
    pvp4=articulo['AR_PVP4'] #liquidacion
    pvp5=articulo['AR_PVP5'] #inicial factory
    pvp6=articulo['AR_PVP6'] #promo factory
    pvp7=articulo['AR_PVP7'] #tarifa 7
    pvp8=articulo['AR_PVP8'] #tarifa 8
    pco=articulo['AR_PCR']     #Precio Coste Real
    vacio=0.0
    if pco==vacio:pco=articulo['AR_PCO']
    pco=pco*2

    pvps = [pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8]

    if any(pvp < pco for pvp in pvps):
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno, pvps])
```

Da error en la última comprobacion, dice que pco no existe.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow en Español, please translate your question.

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido a la comunidad de stackoverflow *en español*. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/317245/edit) para redactarla en castellano.

Comment: Por cierto, En caso de que algún `pvp*` sea inferior a `pco`, ¿debe agregarse un elemento a `dc` por cada uno que sea inferior o con una única vez es suficiente?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Solo una vez, por eso los continues.

Comment: Te hemos dado dos respuestas con varias opciones. Espero que sean de tu agrado.

Comment: Cristian, un consejo, ¿has pensado en introducir los valores en una matriz de datos `pvp[1..8]` con índices numerados en vez de variables con su nombre enumerado? Eso mejoraría mucho la eficiencia del trabajo en bloque con dichos valores.

Comment: ¿En todos lados la tabulación está basada en 4 espacios en blanco? La única explicación es que el `if` esté en un ámbito diferente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Esta todo indexado correctamente.
El error exacto que me da es: global name pco is not defined.

Comment: @CristianGarciaBlasco He extendido la respuesta a la vista de tu EDIT. Mira a ver si he dado en el clavo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay varias formas. La primera y más obvia sería hacer otro bucle para esto:

```
for pvp in [pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8]:
    if pvp < pco:
         dc.append([cdar,ardeno,pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8])
         break
```

El `break` es para que, una vez se ha añadido la lista porque se ha encontrado un caso menor, no se sigan buscando más casos.

Esto puede simplificarse (no conceptualmente, sino sintácticamente) si la ristra de `pvp1`, `pvp2`, etc. la tenemos en una lista. Es más, es posible que puedas modificar la parte del bucle general que lee esos pvp para que los deje en una lista, en lugar de en variables individuales. En todo caso la idea sería:

```
pvps = [pvp1,pvp2,pvp3,pvp4,pvp5,pvp6,pvp7,pvp8]

for pvp in pvps:
    if pvp < pco:
       dc.append([cdar,ardeno, *pvps])
```

Finalmente puedes usar la construcción ligeramente más pythónica usando la función [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(pvp < pco for pvp in pvps):
    dc.append([cdar,ardeno, *pvps])
```

**Nota** sobre esta última. `any()` espera un iterable (en este caso le he pasado una expresión generadora, que hace las veces de iterador), y lo que hace es iterar por esa expresión hasta encontrar un `True`. Tan pronto como lo encuentra `any()` deja de iterar y retorna `True`, de modo que es eficiente pues se detiene tan pronto como es posible. Solo iterará por todos los elementos si todos son `False`, en cuyo caso retornará `False` y la condición del `if` no se cumplirá.

## Edit

Respondiendo al edit de la pregunta.

**Actualizado** (ver último item). <strike>Lo primero, no se comprende cómo puede ser que `pco` no esté definida, pues claramente se le asigna un valor unas líneas antes. ¿Estás seguro de que ese es *exactamente* el código que estás ejecutando? ¿Podrías pegar el mensaje de error completo con el *traceback*? ¿Te funciona si en vez del `any()` vuelves a poner la monstruosidad original con el montón de `if`? Porque al final debería ser lo mismo ya que en esos `if` también se está comparando con `pco` en cada uno...</strike>

Otras cosas:

- En el `dc.append()` has puesto `pvps` al final, en lugar de `*pvps`. Es diferente. Sin el asterisco estás metiendo como último elemento de la lista, otra sublista, es decir el resutado sería equivalente a `[cdar, ardeno, [pvp1, pvp2, ..., pvp8]]`. Con el asterisco *desempaquetas* la sublista y metes sus elementos. Sería equivalente a `[cdar, ardeno, pvp1, pvp2, ..., pvp8]`, que es lo que querías.

  **Actualización** La versión de python del usuario (<=2.5) no soporta el desempaquetado mediante asterisco, así que una alternativa es, en lugar de `[cdar,ardeno, *pvps]`, usar `[cdar,ardeno]+pvps`
- ¡Claro que se puede modificar el bucle externo para que use una lista en vez de variables separadas! Puedes hacer esto:

  ```
  for cdar in articulos:
      articulo=lee('articulos',cdar)
      if articulo==1:
          continue
      ardeno = articulo['AR_DENO']
      pvps = [ articulo['AR_PVP{}'.format(n+1)] for n in range(8)]
      pco = articulo['AR_PCR']     #Precio Coste Real
      vacio = 0.0
      if pco == vacio:
         pco = articulo['AR_PCO']
      pco = pco*2

      if any(pvp < pco for pvp in pvps):
          dc.append([cdar,ardeno, *pvps])
  ```
- Mencionas en un comentario que el error que te da es que "la variable **global** `pco` no está definida". Esto posiblemente se deba a que todo el código que has añadido en el edit, forma parte de una función en la cual tienes declarado al principio `global pco`, pero en cambio no existe la variable global (fuera de la función). Si es esto, el error ya debería aparecerte también con el código original. Puedes arreglarlo poniendo `pco=0.0` fuera de la función

Comment: Mi +1 por la construcción `pvp < pco for pvp in pvps`

Comment: Sobre editar el primer bucle, no es posible, pues el primer bucle recorre una lista de IDs de articulos, utilizando cada ID para leer el articulo entero y así coger las variables necesarias.

Probaré el any y actualizo esto.

Comment: Al añadir el any y probarlo, me da error, diciendo que no encuentra la variable pco.

Añado el codigo desde el bucle.

Edito post original.

Comment: Sobre el asterisco en pvps.
http://prntscr.com/qcy27i

Comment: Qué versión de Python estás usando? En la que yo uso eso funciona. En cualquier caso puedes cambiarlo por `dc.append([cdar,ardeno] + pvps)`

Comment: Uso una antigua, creo que es al 2.3 o la 2.5...

Comment: Igualmente doy por resuelta la pregunta con este comentario. Pues he depurado bastante codigo y los tiempos de ejecución han mejorado en 6 segundos (gestionando 72000 y pico artículos.)

Comment: @CristianGarciaBlasco Lo de 2.3 o 2.5 se avisa! Especialmente ahora que ya la rama 2 ha dejado de recibir actualizaciones y soporte. Y si ni siquiera llega a la 2.7 puede haber muchas respuestas que usen características que no te funcionen. He añadido la etiqueta 2.x a la pregunta. Por cierto, lo de `pco` era lo que yo decía?

Comment: @abulafia Lo del pco era que no conseguia bien el GetValue y quedaba null.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es agregar un elemento si cualquiera de los valores de `pvp*` es inferior a `pco`, entonces puedes buscar el más pequeño con la función [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) y si es inferior a dicho valor, agregarlo a `dc`:

```
if (min(pvp1, pvp2, pvp3, pvp4, pvp5, pvp6, pvp7, pvp8) < cto):
  dc.append([cdar, ardeno, pvp1, pvp2, pvp3, pvp4, pvp5, pvp6, pvp7, pvp8])
```

---

Tras agregar más código a tu pregunta, puedo agregar una respuesta completa, haciendo uso de la función [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) como propuso [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia):

```
def lee(indice, matriz):
  return matriz[indice]

articulos = [
  {
    "articulos": {
      "AR_DENO": "Articulo 1",
      "AR_PVP1": 6.3, "AR_PVP2": 6.3, "AR_PVP3": 6.3, "AR_PVP4": 6.3,
      "AR_PVP5": 9.3, "AR_PVP6": 6.3, "AR_PVP7": 6.3, "AR_PVP8": 6.3,
      "AR_PCR": 15, "AR_PCO": 18,
    }
  },
  {
    "articulos": {
      "AR_DENO": "Articulo 2",
      "AR_PVP1": 6.3, "AR_PVP2": 6.3, "AR_PVP3": 6.3, "AR_PVP4": 6.3,
      "AR_PVP5": 9.3, "AR_PVP6": 6.3, "AR_PVP7": 6.3, "AR_PVP8": 6.3,
      "AR_PCR": 1, "AR_PCO": 2,
    }
  },
]
dc = []

for cdar in articulos:
    articulo=lee('articulos',cdar)
    if articulo==1:continue
    ardeno=articulo['AR_DENO']
    pco=articulo['AR_PCR']     #Precio Coste Real
    vacio=0.0
    if pco==vacio:pco=articulo['AR_PCO']
    pco=pco*2

    pvps = [ articulo[clave] for clave in (
      'AR_PVP1', 'AR_PVP2', 'AR_PVP3', 'AR_PVP4',
      'AR_PVP5', 'AR_PVP6', 'AR_PVP7', 'AR_PVP8'
    ) ]

    if any(pvp < pco for pvp in pvps):
        dc.append([cdar,ardeno, pvps])

print dc
```